# How to conditionally include route parameter in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm trying to allow for one resource, `Site`, to conditionally have a parent resource, `Organization`.

Here's what I currently have:

```
resources :site do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

this results in paths like

```
/sites/1
/sites/1/edit
/sites/1/posts
/sites/1/posts/123/comments
# etc. etc.
```

I want the ability to have paths like

```
/parent_id/sites/1
/parent_id/sites/1/edit
/parent_id/sites/1/posts
/parent_id/sites/1/posts/123/comments
```

but *only if the Site belongs to an Organization*.

I also don't want to have to change every single path helper already in use across my site (there are literally hundreds of places).

Is this possible?

Here's what I've tried:

```
scope "(:organization_id)/", defaults: { organization_id: nil } do
  resources :site
end

# ...

# in application_controller.rb
def default_url_options(options = {})
  options.merge(organization_id: @site.organization_id) if @site&.organization_id
end
```

but that didn't work. `organization_id` wasn't getting set.

```
# in my views
link_to "My Site", site_path(site)
# results in /sites/1 instead of /321/sites/1
```

I also tried setting the organization_id in a route constraint, and that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a monkey patch overriding the dynamic method generated for all of my relevant paths. I used a custom route option, `infer_organization_from_site` that I look for when dynamically generating routes. If the option is set, I add `site.organization` as the first argument to the helper call.

```
# in config/routes.rb

scope "(:organization_id)", infer_organization_from_site: true do
  resources :sites do
    resources :posts
    # etc.
  end
end 

# in an initializer in config/initializers/

module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    # :stopdoc:
    class RouteSet
      class NamedRouteCollection

        private

        # Overridden actionpack-4.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb
        # Before this patch, we couldn't add the organization in the URL when
        # we used eg. site_path(site) without changing it to site_path(organization, site).
        # This patch allows us to keep site_path(site), and along with the proper
        # optional parameter in the routes, allows us to not include the organization
        # for sites that don't have one.
        def define_url_helper(mod, route, name, opts, route_key, url_strategy)
          helper = UrlHelper.create(route, opts, route_key, url_strategy)
          mod.module_eval do
            define_method(name) do |*args|
              options = nil
              options = args.pop if args.last.is_a? Hash
              if opts[:infer_organization_from_site]
                args.prepend args.first.try(:organization)
              end
              helper.call self, args, options
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another block to your routes with the companies resources wrapped around it:

```rb
resources :companies do
  resources :site do
    resources :posts do
      resources :comments
    end
  end
end

resources :site do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Now you can create a helper for your links like this:

```rb
# sites_helper.rb
module SitesHelper
  def link_to_site(text, site)
    if site.company
      link_to text, company_site_path(site.company, site)
    else
      link_to text, site_path(site)      
    end
  end
end
```

Then use it in your view like this:

```rb
<%= link_to_site("Text of the link", variable_name) %>
```

Notice the `variable_name` in the arguments. It can be site or @site, depending on your code. Inside a loop it will probably be site but on a show page I guess it will be @site.

Comment: Thanks, that does work in the simplest case, but unfortunately replacing every single link helper on my site is not something I'm willing to do, as I stated in the question. Each "site" has dozens of pages, each linking to others, so I'd have to create this kind of helper for every single `site_X_path` (and x2 if I want to have the ability to use `site_X_url`.

Comment: In that case I think you didn't thought well about how to organize your app or it is grown that much that you have no other option then modifying every link. Btw, with find and replace it's not that much work to modify the links.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close with your current approach. The problem appears to be that `defaults` on the routing `scope` takes precedence over `default_url_options`, so you'll end up with a nil organization ID every time.

Try instead, just:

```
# in routes.rb
scope "(:organization_id)" do
  resources :site
  ...
end

# in application_controller.rb
def default_url_options(options = {})
  # either nil, or a valid organization ID
  options.merge(organization_id: @site&.organization_id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think we are closer now, but I'm still running into an issue with eg. `site_path(site)`. Rails assumes that the first argument is the `organization_id`, so the `options` passed into `default_url_options` will contain 
`{ organization_id: site.id, id: nil }`. Any further ideas?

Comment: @you786: that's surprising, as the variable is still set up to be optional: `(:organisation_id)`. You could try a) merging in both `id` and `organization_id` from `site`, if that's always an object; b) overriding `site_path` instead and not relying on `default_url_options`